# Symbol for class ranges

Tags: notation

What's name of this symbol for denoting class intervals? How is it input in Latex/MathJax?

[image: Class range symbols]

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/ As mathjax is basically Latex for JavaScript you can ask this here.

Comment: Although asking for the latex is off topic here, asking the name of the symbol and its use is clearly on topic, so I'm inclined to leave this open.

Comment: I've never seen that symbol used for that purpose before. I wouldn't call it a standard or typical use. On the other hand it does seem reasonably clear (it suggests the half-open intervals $[150,154)$ and so forth), so it doesn't seem like a silly idea.

Comment: @Glen_b, so apparently this is more used here in Brazil...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be called the turnstile symbol, see Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turnstile_(symbol)). I would have to say that none of the suggested usages there correspond to what you have in your picture. The article also tells you how to get it in Latex by the way.

Answer (score 3):

As an addition to the answer of mdewey, here is a website where you can draw the symbol you need and get the latex codes for similar looking symbols. It might take 2 or 3 attempts at drawing it, but usually I can find what I need on it:
http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html